# slowly loading ASP web page

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, performance, pagespeed

My Asp.net web site home page take 15-17 second to when typing the address,pressing 'enter' and when there is something (anything) visible on the page. Page has dynamically loading data.
why this is happening and is there any solution to prevent this?

Comment: Which method are you using to connect to database?

Comment: In general, in the very first run, it is normal but from second times and onwards it decreases. If it remains as it is, look into the code that pulls data. See if joins are in your query, try using lesser joins if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boy is this open ended!

Have you investigated;

1. Volume of data being returned
2. Size of page being returned
3. Speed of getting the dynamically generated data
4. Speed of your internet connection
5. Are you returning any images and if so are they large files

Without knowing more about what your site is doing in the backend, there is little for us to suggest in any real sense.

Please provide more information.

Maybe if you post the URL?

Comment: Again, with so little information to go on the only thing i can suggest is to step through your code and identify where it's slow.  if all the code behind is fast then turn off your firewall and security s/ware, slow running javascript before the page is fully rendered, plugins etc

Comment: my company web site and need to add some changes and redesign it